# Best way to pass a variable from outer class to inner class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I'm building an android app (but this is not important for the post) and I'm writing a method called **scrollUntilSelectedAvatar()** that contain a class:

```
public class AvatarManager {

  private HorizontalScrollView avatarPageHorizontalScrollView;

  //mehod that contains the inner class
  public void scrollUntilSelectedAvatar(HorizontalScrollView avatarPageHorizontalScrollView){

        this.avatarPageHorizontalScrollView = avatarPageHorizontalScrollView;

        avatarPageHorizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AvatarManager.this.avatarPageHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(100, 0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My question is: what's the correct way to access **avatarPageHorizontalScrollView** (that I pass to the method as an argument) inside the inner class `new Runnable()`.

The way I found (`AvatarManager.this.avatarPageHorizontalScrollView`) doesn't seems the best way.

Thank everybody for the help :)

Comment: Why do you think your way is incorrect?

Comment: Dunno, I thought there was a better way to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did it - is the one and only correct. Syntax of some thing about inner classes may seem quite strange. But it is just like it is.

```java
public class A {

    private int a;

    private abstract class B {
        public abstract void printA();
    }

    public B makeB() {
        return new B() {
            @Override
            public void printA() {
                System.out.println(A.this.a);
            }
        };
    }
}
```